# How to remove broken threaded water pipe

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, water, plumbing-fixture

The pipe connecting my shower head to the wall has broken off. I removed the head and tried to remove the theaded pipe but the potruding metal broke off completely. Is there anyway to remove the part that's still stuck without drilling the wall and replace the pipe? Landlord would kill me for that.

Comment: Don't know where you are, but isn't maintenance the Landlord's responsibility?

Answer (score 4):

There is a tool that will remove the pipe. It works on the inside of the pipe so it needs none of the pipe to grab onto. This [one set](http://www.harborfreight.com/5-piece-pipe-nipple-extractor-set-93822.html) may work, but [this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/1-2-PIPE-NIPPLE-EXTRACTOR-REMOVER-INTERNAL-PIPE-REMOVER-/170628697069) is the type I think is more reliable.

Comment: @Van If Jack's answer was what you needed, it's good to mark it as the answer your question by clicking the checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 1):

Many angle valves which are on the market, are not made of brass, but are zinc castings.
They tend to deteriorate over a few years and tend to break off flush with the fitting in the wall.
Using easy outs or rawl bolts, etc. to extract the remnants often fail as the wall thickness of the scrap in the wall is extremely thin.
I have found that tapping a groove into the remainder and then chipping the scrap out piece by piece, works best.
Then trial fit the new angle valve before adding PTFE, thread tape, rather than Hemp.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, props for [taking our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) before posting; few newbies do.

Answer (score 0):

Is it actually pipe thats left in the wall? This happened in my bathroom but it was actually just a cheap piece of PVC type plastic made to look like metal that broke off.
If it is actually the cheap plastic, we cut it very carefully with a hack saw blade taken out of the actual hacksaw. The blade itself is small enough to fit in the space and we did two cuts (at about 4:30 and 7:00 positions if you look at it and pretend it's a clock). Just go slow and easy. It won't take to much extra time to go slow.
You will be able to take it out in two pieces or three.
Good luck. If it was plastic, opt for the new metal piece when you replace it!

Comment: Thanks. It's actually metal unfortunately. I tried cutting it with a saw blade as you said but only some kind of gray coating come off. I wonder if there's some kind of tool that can be inserted and expanded inside so we can turn it like a screw to remove. I remember seeing that kind of tool but don't know what it's called.

Answer (score 0):

Just had this same problem with irrigation in front yard. I can't think of its generic name but it's also called a nipple extractor. You can get a set at Lowes or Home Depot for 20-30.
See YouTube video and how to do it: 
http://youtu.be/8Wns8rs1mVc

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem before. What i did was to use a hachsaw blade. I made 2 cuts about 5 mm apart and remove that part tapping it with small screw driver and hammer. You can now remove the rest of embedded part by tapping. Make sure that you dont damage the pipe thread.It will take some time to cut with a hacksaw blade.